# Google Sheets Auto HyperLink to Google Earth Web?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-earth

Was wondering if there's simple way to convert column which is full with addresses to hyperlink for Google Earth web.

If you try https://earth.google.com/web/search/New York it will show New York, which means
that I need https://earth.google.com/web/search/ & self_cell_value somehow, of course the text of the hyperlink can be whatever the text (address) is inside the cell.

Any tips how to do this easy ? Arrayformula and stuff need to be placed onto another column/cells, which is something that I don't want. Just the column of addresses converted into hyperlinks as mentioned. Upon adding new addresses it should be automatically happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample script that will trigger when column `A` in `Sheet1` is edited, it will take the values and replace the space with `+`.

So `https://earth.google.com/web/search/New York` will change to `https://earth.google.com/web/search/New+York` automatically.

You can edit the column number or the sheet name as required.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // get the range where the edit once done
  let range = e.range

  // get the column number where the changes is done
  let working_range = range.getColumn()

  // the Sheet name where the change is done
  let sheet = e.source.getSheetName(); 

  // if statement, if the change was done in Sheet1 
  //and column 1 (column A), the script will trigger
  if (sheet == 'Sheet1' & working_range==1){ 

      // get the range value in column A
      let cell_value = range.getValue().toString();

      // replace the space with a +
      let new_cell_value = cell_value.replace(' ', '+')

      //sets the hyperlink
      let richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(new_cell_value)
      .setLinkUrl(new_cell_value)
      .build();
      range.setRichTextValue(richValue);
  }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: sample]

#### Update:

If you add, just one word instead of a URL, you can make this changes to the code to create the hyperlink:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // get the range where the edit once done
  let range = e.range

  // get the column number where the changes is done
  let working_range = range.getColumn()

  // the Sheet name where the change is done
  let sheet = e.source.getSheetName(); 

  // if statement, if the change was done in Sheet1 
  //and column 1 (column A), the script will trigger
  if (sheet == 'Sheet1' & working_range==1){ 

      // get the range value in column A
      let cell_value = range.getValue().toString();

      // replace the space with a +
      let new_cell_value = cell_value.replace(' ', '+')

      //sets the hyperlink with the current value in the column 
      // and the URL to Google Earth withut the space 
      let richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(cell_value)
      .setLinkUrl("https://earth.google.com/web/search/" + new_cell_value)
      .build();
      range.setRichTextValue(richValue);
  }
}
```

[image: new update sample]

**Reference:**

- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetname)
- [getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed example BUT this is almost of what I requested again. 
The A fields are "New York", "San Francisco" etc and not pasted hyperlink on the initial stage (just simple text).  This "New York" must be used for the hyperlink TEXT only. The hyperlink should be clickable and leading to https://earth.google.com/web/search/New+York .
Thanks

Comment: @Svetoslav, let me do some changes to the code. Just to confirm, the user will type or copy `New York` in the cell, and the code should change it to a hyperlink like this: e.g., [New York](https://earth.google.com/web/search/New+York) . (pointing to Google earth), is that correct?

Comment: This is correct yes !

Comment: Okay, I got it. I will update the answer now.

Comment: @Svetoslav, I added the code as an update. It should work now. I will add a GIF in a few minutes.

Comment: Works like a charm ! I was even thinking for more complicated thing to do this without script but ArrayFormula or something but I guess that's the only option, which is OK for my needs.
Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'm happy to hear that it works for you. Sorry that I misunderstood the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula and a **drop-down**

```
="https://earth.google.com/web/search/"&C2
```

**OR**
You may want to use a **range**

```
=INDEX(IF(B6:B="",,$A$5&B6:B))
```

In any case, locations having more than 1 word must be joined using the `+` sign

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: I can see you are using 2 columns and this is not the point. As you have B, the link should be automatically clickable without the of need A column at all. Maybe this is doable with scripting but I don't know how.